# better way to write code when multiple query parameters are present

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs

I've a controller `xyz.controller.ts`

```
@Get()
fetch(
 @Query('id') id: number,
 @Query('status') status: string, 
 @Query('country_id') countryId: number,
 @Query('state_id') stateId: number): Promise<any> {
     return await this.xyzService(id, status, countryId, stateId);
}
```

Is there any way to pass the query params as a single object instead of creating multiple function args?

Answer (score 1):

if you specify the key in the query, it will only return the value of that key, but if you just write `@Query() query` it will return the whole query object and then you can create a interface to give a type to the query object, `@Query() query: IQuery`